# Connecting between terminal 1 and 2 at SFO

Tags: air-travel, transit, sfo

Can I walk between terminals 1 and 2 at SFO or do I have to use air Train?  Do I have to reclear TSA?

Comment: Terminal 2 is the old International Terminal, which is why the connections are as weak as they are.

Answer (score 2):

You can always walk between the terminals outside of the secure area without having to ride AirTrain.

There is [a secure connector](http://milesfromblighty.boardingarea.com/2015/08/13/the-connection-terminals-2-and-1-sfo/) between Terminal 2 and part of Terminal 1 at SFO that allows you to do so without going through security again. Note that this connector only connects the D gates in Terminal 2 with the C gates in Terminal 1 (formerly known as gates 40-48); to the best of my knowledge, you'd need to go through security again to get to the B gates (formerly gates 20-39).

Answer (score 0):

I made a video showing all of SFO so you can see what you're up against:
https://youtu.be/xCHw8lN4L2k
I talk about how to change terminals even when you don't have a ticket there for the same day.

Comment: Welcome to Travel! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here (e.g. a transcript), and provide the link for reference.